# Page does not redirect when using the action param

Tags: apex, javascript, actionfunction

I am getting the error when am redirecting from the javascript it show the cross domain issue.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using JS instead of a standard <apex:commandButton>?

Comment: Yes. thats existing implementation. so can  you guid me how to redirect the page.

Comment: Is jQuery being included on your page somewhere? I don't believe jQuery is available by default in visualforce pages and I don't see a script include tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please disable the popup and try with the two section / form

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked about , here's how that would look:

```
<apex:page controller="TestController" showHeader="true" sidebar="true">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" id="theButton" immediate="true"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

with a corresponding method in your controller:

```
public with sharing class TestController {

    public TestController() {

    }

    public PageReference save () {

        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/home/home.jsp');

        pr.setRedirect(true);

        return pr;
    }
}
```

[Documentation here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_commandButton.htm)

I like to use VF components over HTML / JS where possible.

Edit: I think that may be your problem, you're trying to call the controller every time:

```
<apex:page controller="testmethod" >

<apex:actionFunction name="testJS" action="{!testmethod}" reRender="outPanel">
```

The controller in the first line of code is the Apex class in which testmethod() is defined.

Edit 2:

Try this simplified page code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="MyApexClass" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel >name</apex:outputLabel>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="name" size="50"  />
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>   
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom" >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!callMethod}" reRender="messagePanel"/>     
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>   
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Can you look my question above?  The apex code is working but it is not redirect. I dont know the reason

Comment: try 'pr.setRedirect(true);' before returning it.

Comment: Yes i have tried that as well but not help. I saw the console it shows the error. see the image in my question.

Comment: If i use the PageReference secondPage = page.vfpag. it is redirect. but if i use the url it is not redirect.

Comment: Strange, I just tested with a test VF page & controller and it works fine - please see updated code.

Also, you have in your page:
<apex:page controller="testmethod" >

Isn't testmethod the action method you should be invoking with the button, not the page controller?

Comment: I have simplify the code. can you test the above code?

Comment: I've updated my answer with new page code, give that a try.

Comment: But if I use the page.vfpage, work fine. can you resolve the issue form my question.

Comment: Try the code I posted above, and then if that works start adding in the javascript etc. you want piece by piece and you'll find the problem.

Comment: Not work. did you tried in your org?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17022/discussion-between-lemon-and-davinc).

Answer (score 0):

For your example, you definitely don't need jQuery. Just use plain old javascript.
Also, you can call your action function directly from your input by adding an `onclick` listener.

Finally in your controller, you need to add a `setRedirect(true)` so that the system knows to reload the page - only required if you are going to reload or go to a page with the same controller as the one you are already using.

Here is some code that should do close to what you need:

**PAGE:**

```
<apex:page standardController="CustomObject__c" extensions="MyApexClass" showHeader="false" sidebar="false"
standardStylesheets="true" docType="html-5.0" >
    <apex:outputField value="{!VoiceOfTheCustomer__c.Name}" rendered="false"/>
    <label>{!RecordName}</label>
    <script>
    function testRedirectJS(obj){
      var theName = document.getElementById('name');
      testRedirect(theName);
    }
    </script>
    <apex:form>
        <input type="button" onclick="testRedirectJS(this)" value="Submit Value" id="submit" class="btn" />
        <apex:actionFunction name="testRedirect" action="{!testRedirect}" reRender="outPanel">
        <apex:param assignTo="{!name}" name="psName" value=""/>
        </apex:actionFunction>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public with sharing class MyApexClass {

    private final sObject mysObject;
    public String name {get;set;}

    public MyApexClass(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.mysObject = (sObject)stdController.getRecord();
    }

    public String getRecordName() {
        return 'Hello ' + (String)mysObject.get('name') + ' (' + (Id)mysObject.get('Id') + ')';
    }

    public PageReference testRedirect() {
        PageReference ref = new PageReference('/' + (Id)mysObject.get('Id'));
        ref.setRedirect(true);
        return ref;

    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you actually need to use jQuery - it appears you do, given that you have updated your code to include a jQuery component, then make sure you include it either as a static resource or as a dynamic reference.

If you want to make sure that your action function is working properly, remove everything except the button and it's call to the controller function. If it works (and it will - I've verified that my example works on my own org), then you know that whatever errors you are getting are Javascript related.

These Javascript errors are probably due to you not successfully including JQuery in your page. Once you have sorted that out, it should all work.

You can debug the page as it calls the ActionFunction in the console - locate you code and set a breakpoint.

Finally, make sure that `setRedirect` is being called like so:

```
PageReference ref = new PageReference('/' + (Id)mysObject.get('Id'));
ref.setRedirect(true);
```

If none of this works, it's likely that you have not provided that code that contains the error in your example.

Comment: Where you use the testRedirectJS? in actionfunction

Comment: So, if you need to add a tricker parameter, you can call testRedirectJS() from the button, get your param (via document.getElementById('someid') or by some other means), and then call testRedirect(someid). Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you update in your answer. I have tried but not redirect. i just confusing when using the  $j = jQuery.noConflict(); so is this need or not. above my code is working fine but the problem is not redirect. how can to make the redirect?

Comment: ok, so I've updated. I'm getting an item called 'name' (you'll have to add it). You don't need jQuery. Remove it. As people above have said, you have not included jQuery, so it's going to break everything. Also, if you don't need to pass a parameter to the controller, don't include that either.

Comment: To clarify - you have no need of anything to do with jQuery in your code. You can remove it all.

Comment: var printedName = $j('#name').val();     equal to          var theName = document.getElementById('name'); right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17020/discussion-between-caspnz-and-lemon).

Comment: Hmm, chat not working for me.

Comment: Anyway, var printedName = $j('#name').val(); <> to var theName = document.getElementById('name'); - getElementById, gets the whole element - you'll need to get the element.value. Use your Javascript debugger to find out which particular object attribute you need.

Comment: Could you please do one thing. my code is working fine but the redirect is the problem due to some through exception in console. so implement another method in my code for redirect. can you help? i dont want to collapse the existing javascript funciton. just add the method in apex for redirect. how to do?

Comment: any update please?

Comment: Sorry you'll have to wait a bit - I have to go.

Comment: Ok i will wait.  may I know when will i get the update please. I will wait.

Comment: Ok, added more detail to the answer. I can't help any more than this - it's up to you now.

Comment: Yes i have tried the separate page in your code but it shows the error. see the image in my question

Comment: I have updated your exact code now please check.

Answer (score -3):

Open your browser console. You should be able to find the error. From where i can see, you don't have a parameter in your testmethod() but are trying to call a method that accepts a parameter from the javascript. either you add the parameter to your method signature or remove it from the VF page. That should fix the issue. Hope this helps.

Comment: Console should throw jquery not found to start with

Comment: Flamesavor are you mentioning apex class testmethod()? I have checked in log. that method is executed.